# WinForms designer adding duplicated nodes to subclass of TreeView

Tags: c#, winforms, treeview, windows-forms-designer

I created a subclass of the System.Windows.Forms.TreeView class with some default TreeNodes:

```
public class SimulationTreeView : TreeView
{
    private TreeNode unitLoadsNode;

    private TreeNode conveyorsNode;

    private TreeNode aislesNode;

    public SimulationTreeView()
    {
        this.unitLoadsNode = this.Nodes.Add("Unit Loads");
        this.conveyorsNode = this.Nodes.Add("Conveyors");
        this.aislesNode = this.Nodes.Add("Aisles");
    }
}
```

When I add the control to a form using the designer and I run the code, I get the following result:

[Result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nTXgO.png)

The TreeNodes are duplicated, because the designer generates code to add them in addition to the nodes already generated at the constructor of the class.
I could easily delete the generated code in the designer file, but it is far from ideal because I would need to change the generated code everytime I change my TreeView subclass.

How is a TreeView subclass supposed to be implemented without running into this problem? Consider that I will add events and other properties to this subclass.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to override or shadow the `Nodes` property and add `[DesignerSerializationVisiblity(DesignerSerializationVisiblity.Hidden)]`.

This will tell the designer to stop serialization the property.

Note that you'll have to re-open and re-save (after recompiling) every designer that uses your control for it to actually update the `.Designer.cs` files.

Comment: How can I override the `Nodes` property? When I try doing that, I cannot  initialize it because its type `TreeNodeCollection` has no constructors.

Comment: @Seiken: Your override should just return `base.Nodes`.  All you need is to add the attribute.